# Clarifying statsmodels AutoReg(), ARMA() and SARIMAX() for time-series forecasting

Tags: statsmodels

I am buidling my first time-series prediction model with scikit-learn's LinearRegression(). I also came across statsmodels AutoReg(), ARMA() and SARIMAX(). Unfortunately out of the literature I could not figure out to consider them. Are they alternatives to LinearRegression()? Are they ML? Are they fundamental different?

I'd appreciate a hint, where to look further. Thanks.

Comment: Here you'll find what you need to know about ARIMA, SARIMAX etc https://machinelearningmastery.com/?s=arima&post_type=post&submit=Search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three fit variants of Seasonal Autoregressive Integrated Moving Average with eXogenous Variables (SARIMAX) models.

### `AutoReg`

`AutoReg` is limited to only Autoregressive Models and so does not include Seasonal or Moving Average components.  It does support exogenous regressors.  It also supports complex deterministic processes such as Fourier series to model multiple seasonalities. Parameters are estimated using OLS which is equivalent to conditional maximum likelihood.  Since parameters are estimated using OLS, estimation is very fast and completely deterministic.

### `ARIMA`

`ARIMA` is a restricted version of `SARIMAX` that does not include Seasonal components or Exogenous regressors.  Because it excludes these two types of terms, it can offer additional fitting options that are not available when fitting a full SARIMAX model. These have different statistical properties than the Maximum Likelihood method that is the only method available in `SARIMAX` (`ARIMA` also supports Maximum Likelihood). Many of these alternative parameter estimation methods are also faster than ML.

### `SARIMAX`

`SARIMAX` supports all features of `ARIMA` plus the two additional components.  It can only be estimated using Maximum Likelihood. ML uses numerical methods to maximize the function and so estimation of some series/models may encounter difficulties converging.

The [examples page](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/index.html) is the best place to look to see the detailed use of these models.  Many of the notebooks include both code examples and LaTeX markup that explains the underlying math.